Separating differentiable numerical solutions of high order formula
Suppose there is an equation w.r.t. $z$:
$f(a_1,a_2,...)(z)=0$
where $f$ is some Laurent polynomial, all parameters and variables are complex. Given a range of parameters, is there a numerical method to separately show its numerical solutions each differentiable w.r.t. each parameter?
For instance, we know the solutions for $az^2+bz+c=0$ are
$z=\frac{-b\pm(b^2-4ac)^{1/2}}{2a}$
we hope the method separates the plus and minus solution branch even if the $b^2-4ac=0$ points are included in the parameter range.
About background: in some dynamical systems, we hope to track the change of such solutions w.r.t. parameters. Mathematica or similar software can easily solve for all the solution branches, but cannot separate them.
Probably we can try to check the continuity of derivatives and higher derivatives of solutions w.r.t. parameters, which should be useful in many cases, since inverse of holomorphic functions are holomorphic. What other tools do we have, if said derivatives are the same at intersection?
